# Simple integral with a logarithmic function: $\int\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider this indefinite integral and solve it with the simplest way.

$$\int\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,\mathrm dx$$

How  can we  solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take as known the integral

$$\int \ln x\,dx = x\ln x-x+C$$

Start with the substitution $x=1-u^2$, so that $\sqrt{1-x}=u$ and $dx=-2udu$.  We have

$$\int{\ln x\over\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx=-2\int\ln(1-u^2)\,du=-2\int\ln(1-u)\,du-2\int\ln(1+u)\,du$$

Each of the last two integrals can be handled as a straightforward substitution from the known integral of the logarithm function.

Note:  Short of simply differentiating $x\ln x-x$ and verifying you get $\ln x$, I can't offhand think of any way to integrate $\ln x$ without at some point using integration by parts.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the substitution $u = 1 - x$ and then apply integration by parts.

Edit:
Using the given substitution, we get (neglecting the negative sign, which you can add in in your work)
$$\int \frac{\ln(1 - u)}{\sqrt{u}}\,\mathrm{d}u = 2\sqrt{u}\ln(1 - u) + 2 \int\frac{\sqrt{u}}{1 - u}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
The last integral can be easily evaluated by putting $u = v^2$.

Comment: How u=1-x helps?

Comment: It's a matter of preference really - the key here is to use integration by parts.

Comment: I can't.If it is possible please give more hints.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps

i) Using integration by parts with $u=\ln(x)$ gives

> $$ -2\,\sqrt {1-x}\ln  \left( x \right) -\int \!-2\,{\frac {\sqrt {1-x}}{
> x}}{dx}.$$

ii) applying the change of variables $1-x=u^2$ yields

> $$ -2\,\sqrt {1-x}\ln  \left( x \right) +4\,\int \!{\frac {{u}^{2}}{{u}^{
> 2}-1}}{du}
> . $$

iii) To evaluate the last integral use the partial fraction technique

> $$ \frac{u^2}{u^2-1}=1-\frac{1}{2(1+u)}+ \frac{1}{2(u-1)}. $$

Answer (score 3):

Beter make the substitution $z=\sqrt{1-x}$. Then $x=1-z^2$ $dx=-2zdz$
$$\int \frac{\ln (1-z^2)}{z}(-2z dz)=-2\int\ln(1-z^2)dz$$
Now $U=\ln (1-z^2), dU=-\frac{2z}{1-z^2}$,  $dV=dz, V=z$ and an integration by parts gives
$$\int \ln(1-z^2)dz=z\ln (1-z^2)+2\int  \frac{z^2}{1-z^2}dz$$
$$=z\ln (1-z^2)-2\int  \frac{z^2-1+1}{z^2-1}dz$$
$$=z\ln (1-z^2)-2\int dz-2\int \frac{1}{z^2-1}dz=etc.$$